# How to create an objects-only project for Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm working on a custom build tool that can export Visual Studio VS2010 .vcxproj files.  I've run into some cases where a project builds only objects, i.e. like a crt0 startup object.  It appears the ConfigurationType property of the PropertyGroup element only expects "Application", "StaticLibrary", "DynamicLibrary", "Utility", or "Unknown".  Therefore I use "StaticLibrary", and just let it build an unused library to build the desired object, as using the executable types depend on missing startup symbols.  However, if an application project that links against the build object file has a dependency on the object project, it implicity links against the static library output, causing duplicate symbol errors in the link.  A constraint is that I can't change the input to the custom build tool, therefore I need to find some way to deal with it purely withing the project file exporter.

For example, is there some way in the project file to turn off the implicit link against a specific dependent project library output?

Another data point is that my specific cases use the ProDG Playstation 3  VSI plugin, but I think this still just involves standard Visual Studio stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The ProjectReference element can take the element:

`<LinkLibraryDependencyInputs>false</LinkLibraryDependencyInputs>`

This turns off the automatic inclusion.

Comment: This turns off automatic linking for all dependencies not only for your crt.